# Grails GORM Querying the many side of an association using HQL

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

I have a one to many relationship between a Course and Categories

```
class Course {

    String code     

    static hasMany = [categories:CourseCategory]
}


Class CourseCategory {

    String name
}
```

I need to query courses based on a list of categories. I have tried the query

```
courseInstanceList = Course.findAll("from Course c inner join c.categories cts where cts.id in :categoryIds",[categoryIds:categoryIds])
```

But this query returns both Courses and CourseCategories - just wondering how to create a query to just return courses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [createCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) method:

```
def c = Course.createCriteria()
println (c.listDistinct {
    categories {
        'in' 'id', [1L, 2L, 3L]
    }
})
```

Comment: This query returns courses that have any of the category ids specified. Is it possible to only return courses that have all the category ids specified?

Answer (score 0):

Almost three years past ... )

Anyway here's the answer:

```
courseInstanceList = Course.findAll("SELECT distinct c from Course c inner join c.categories cts where cts.id in :categoryIds",[categoryIds:categoryIds])
```

to get just categories:

```
courseInstanceList = Course.findAll("SELECT cts from Course c inner join c.categories cts where cts.id in :categoryIds",[categoryIds:categoryIds])
```